# What is the simplest way to join multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have been working as a data analyst for about 4 months now and the above is a very real question for me. The most recent way I've been taught to join is with the left join with the following example.

```
left join table1
on
table2.id = table1.id

left join table2
on
table3.table_id = table2.table_id

left join table4
on
table1.tablekey_id = table4.tablekey_id
```

Looking for the most efficient way to connect multiple tables to save time, if possible.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What you have is perfectly fine and uses the appropriate modern syntax for joining tables. Tuning will depend entirely on specific cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplest way to join"?  If you have to JOIN a table, there's no getting around a JOIN expression.

Comment: What I meant was, is there a shorter syntax available? @squillman My aim is to avoid writing out the code as shown in the example. So, if I can use some combination of left/right/full/outer/inner to join 3 or more tables, that is what I'm looking to ascertain.

Comment: @elangley - "shorter" is not always "more elegant". Even if there *were* a way to smash them into a one-liner, having the separate `JOIN` statements clarifies the intent and is more-maintainable for future onlookers.  :)

Comment: Considering the information required to specify a join I think it fairly obvious you couldn't get anything much simpler, because all the information shown is required to specify the joins. You could use table alises to save some typing

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a `NATURAL JOIN`, but while that syntax is supported by several DBMSs (such as Oracle and MySql, ), MS SQL Server is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly use a shorter alias for the table names and table fields.

Example: 
`Table 1 = alias t1` 
`tablekey_id = tkid`

So then it would `t1.tkid` instead of having to type out `table1.tablekey_id`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is only two tables of same columns and same datatypes, you can use union concept to join the tables.
2. You can also join tables like this:

Tables: TableA, TableB

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.id = TableB.id;
```

Comment: about your second option:  [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)   (Note: a 13 year old article, telling something is old ....)